# ShieldUI Grid with LoadingPanel

Tags: grid, shieldui

I am using Shield UI Grid to populate a grid from our database.  There is a lot of data and it takes a little while to load.  On page load from another page, the default Shield UI LoadingPanel is displayed which is good.  The problem is when somebody needs to pick a different section instead of default.  When the submit button is pressed, the code behind is activated to retrieve the new data based on the new section.  The default Shield UI LoadingPanel doesn't display...so the user can't tell if anything is going on until the data changes.

Do I need to reset the Grid to activate the LoadingPanel?  If so, how?

[On Page Loading...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwXFa.png)

[When Submit Clicked...want to see the Loading Panel like image above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxQuE.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can control the Grid's loading panel through its `.loadingPanel` property.

Here is the [LoadingPanel documentation](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/loadingpanel/javascript/api/methods).

If you want to show a loading indicator for your whole page, you will need to add a separate panel for it, as shown in the [examples](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/loadingpanel/basic-usage).